# change timezone mysql without root

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone, hosting

I have mySQL database in a free hosting web (because of that I can't set timezone).
When I make 'now()' sentence, It shows me the hour with GMT+8, and I need it with GMT+1.

Are there any way to change it or modify the result without root access??

Thank You in advance and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one command for set timezone in mysql `set time_zone = '+05:30';`

Comment: but when I make "select now()" time don't change.

Comment: does the execution of the command gives you some kind of error or warning ?? if no then it has to be changed. try exact gmt+1 this command `set time_zone = '+01:00';`

Comment: when I execute that it says "Your SQL query has been executed successfully";

But later when I execute "Select now();" the response is "2013-04-01 08:11:43".

Comment: I tried with non-root user and after command its showing me `2013-04-01 13:15:50`. possibly the user doesnt has a permission for system param modification.

Comment: If its not working with your user access. then for there is one another alternative use timezone converter in mysql whenever you fire select query like `select convert_tz(now() or your fieldname,'+05:30','+01:00');` it will conver gmt+05:30 to gmt+01:00